# Regex to find multiple words in different order

Tags: regex

I am trying to find all occurrences (there could be zero or more) of anchor(`<a>`) HTML tags with specific attributes/text (to be captured as groups). But the groups (attributes) **can occur in any order**.

**Regex for fixed order that works fine**:

```
<a\s+.*attr1="myattr".*attr2="(.+)".*attr3="(.+)".*>(.+)</a>
```

**Tried the following regex for different order without success**:

```
<a\s+.*?((attr1="myattr".*?attr2="(.+?)".*?attr3="(.+?)")|(attr1="myattr".*?attr3="(.+?)".*?attr2="(.+?)")|(attr2="(.+?)".*?attr3="(.+?)".*?attr1="myattr")|(attr2="(.+?)".*?attr1="myattr".*?attr3="(.+?)")|(attr3="(.+?)".*?attr2="(.+?)".*?attr1="myattr")|(attr3="(.+?)".*?attr1="myattr".*?attr2="(.+?)")).*?>(.+?)</a>
```

**Input String for different order of attributes**:

```
First <a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</a>Second <a attr1="myattr" attr3="value13" attr2="value12">text2</a> Third <a attr2="value12" attr1="myattr" attr3="value13">text3</a>`
```

Comment: What **language**? Don't use regex, use a parser for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead instead of normal matching (but in jeneral you shouldn't use regex for parsing html):

```
/<a\s+(?=[^>]*\battr1\s*=\s*"myattr")(?=[^>]*\battr2\s*=\s*"([^"]+?)")(?=[^>]*\battr3\s*=\s*"([^"]+?)")[^>]*>(.+?)<\/a>/
```

```js
`
  <a attr1="myattr" attr2="smth" attr3="3">123</a>
  <a attr1="myattr" attr3="3" attr2="smth">132</a>
  <a attr2="smth" attr1="myattr" attr3="3">213</a>
  <a attr2="smth" attr3="3" attr1="myattr">231</a>
  <a attr3="3" attr1="myattr" attr2="smth">312</a>
  <a attr3="3" attr2="smth" attr1="myattr">321</a>
`.replace(
  /<a\s+(?=[^>]*\battr1\s*=\s*"myattr")(?=[^>]*\battr2\s*=\s*"([^"]+?)")(?=[^>]*\battr3\s*=\s*"([^"]+?)")[^>]*>(.+?)<\/a>/g,
  (match, attr2, attr3, text) => console.log(text, attr2, attr3, match)
)
```